# Error 10 in ionic native google plus login

Tags: angular, ionic4, google-plus-signin

I am using ionic native `google plus login` but I am getting error 10 after doing the same.

Below is my code :-

```
 doGoogleLogin(){
    this.googlePlus.login({})
      .then(res => {
        this.router.navigate(['./tabs']);
        this.userInfo = JSON.stringify(res);
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
        this.userInfo = JSON.stringify(err);
      })
  }
```

Comment: Could you please share the error stack ?

Comment: @Boobalan the only error that I am getting is digit 10 .

Comment: You are telling that the value "err" param in catch block is digit 10 ?

Comment: @Boobalan yes right

Comment: Quite strange ! You could rise an issue ticket to cordova plugin repository

Comment: @Boobalan its not about cordova plugin. It's when I am logging in to the Google , response from that is coming 10.

Comment: May be this link useful to you https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/243

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Searching 4 days i figured out you have to do simple steps do that carefully.

1 first check your ionic version

if it ionic 3

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
 $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid
 $ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-plus@4
```

Add this plugin to your app's module

2.go to Google Cloude Console

[Google Cloude Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient)

3.create Auth2

4.add your app id that `com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx`

Comment: I am trying to install ionic-native google plus plugin which requires me to add app bundle id in command itself. But I have two different bundle ids for android and ios. How can I deal with this situation, any idea??

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution. I knew there was something to do with cordova not signing the APK with my  `~/.android/debug.keystore` file, so I created a debug-signing.properties file in the `platforms/android` folder and specified there the keystone path, password etc.

Things worked fine after that

Cheers !

`debug-signing.properties` file structure

```
keyAlias=yourkeyAlias

keyPassword=yourkeyPassword

storeFile=theFileContainingTheKeystore

storePassword=yourStorePassword
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the solution I just run

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

**password:** android

Copied SHA-1 and created a new OAuth2 with that hash

Visit: [Github reply](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/243#issuecomment-245908012)

Answer (score 0):

I was using *Android Client ID* instead of **Web Client Id**. Once I changed it to `webClientId`, it worked.

Below is from google developer console, use the client ID from the web client in your Android app.

[image: web client id]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little late to give the answer but still, it will help someone.

You may have not added your release JKS SHA-1 Key in your google cloud console.

just type the keytool command with your release jks path

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "path to jks file\keystore.jks" -alias release-1
```

[image]

you will get the SHA-1 from here now go to GC console and Create Credentials
[image]

Now Select your application type and add SHA-1 in the place now Click on Create and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above did not work for me, The SHA-1 fingerprint of the sign-in key used during the build process did not WORK, but instead, the key which is provided in Google developer play console under App Integrity->App signing worked, on this page, you will find 2 keys 1 is for use while authenticating with any API vendors and the other one is just a store for the same sign-in key that is used during the build process, this is for the reason in case if we happen to lose the key, should be able to safely download from here. I struggled with this issue for many days and finally resolved it. As the specs keep changing, it's important to look for the latest answers to save us some time. Hope this would help someone before it would no longer work!

[image]